# Load the Canopy Editor for Python directly from command line in Linux?

Tags: python, editor, canopy

I was just wondering if there was a way to do this. It takes a few minutes to load the whole Canopy thing, just for me to click on "Editor" and then x-click the first window. Is there a way to just load the Canopy Editor immediately?

If not, is there a more lightweight editor that has the same functionality as the Canopy Editor for Python 2.7x that loads faster?

Comment: If you're okay with two windows, you can just run `ipython` from command line for the shell, and just use pretty much any other text editor.

Comment: FWIW, most people using Canopy just leave it open all day, than the load time becomes a rounding error. Also FYI if you quit / restart, the startup time is much quicker because the cache is warm.